# Redirect To Root Not Happening In Custom User Login View function

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am newbie to python and Django. I tried every tool (chatgpt, Youtube, blogs) but I was unable to find the solution.

****Problem Statement:****
When I fill the sign-up form, after submission, I am directed to login page. Here when I enetr correct credentials, instead of redirecting me to "home" view function, the login page remain appearing/stayed on the screen.I asked Chatgpt, according to it, redirection is not happening properly. Please help

when I typed correct credentials in login form and hit the submit button following error appears in the terminal [**27/Aug/2023 05:22:34] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1078**]

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,Group, Permission
  
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField("email address", unique=True)
    username= models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, 
                               help_text=
                               'Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.',
                                 max_length=150, unique=True, null=True, verbose_name='username')
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name='groups',
        blank=True,
        help_text='The groups this user belongs to.',
        related_name='custom_users',  # Add a unique related_name
    )

    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        related_name='custom_users',  
    )


    USERNAME_FIELD = "email" 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", 'password', "email",'first_name', 'last_name',)
         #fields= '__all__'
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username Here'})
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password Here'})
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email Here'})
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name Here'})
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name Here'})
    )



class LogInForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Email',
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your email'}),
        max_length=100  # Add a max length validation
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your password'}),
        max_length=100,  # Add a max length validation
        help_text='Your password must contain at least 8 characters.'  # Add help text
    )
```

**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import SignUpForm, LogInForm


def Home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            clean_data = form.cleaned_data
            new_user = SignUpForm(clean_data)
            new_user.save()
            return redirect('backend_:login')

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()   
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})



def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LogInForm(request.POST)
        if not form.is_valid():
            print("Form errors:", form.errors)
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid email or password')
        else:
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'You have been logged in')
                return redirect('backend_:home')  
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid email or password')
    else:
        form = LogInForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})



def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'Sorry to see you go')
    return redirect('/')
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import signup, log_in, log_out, Home

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home, name='home'),
    path('signup/', signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', log_in, name='login'),
    path('logout/', log_out, name='logout'),
    
]
```

**Login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}


<h2>Log In</h2>
<form method="POST" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

  Your are logged in {{ request.user.username }}!

  <p><a href="{% url 'backend_:logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>

{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'backend_:login' %}">Log In</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'backend_:signup' %}">Sign Up</a>|
  <a href="{% url 'backend_:logout' %}">Log out</a>|


{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How to know you it is the right username and password, put a print statement in each block to check is the user is NONE or not

Comment: @Mohamed ElKalioby I put the print statement for email and password just above                                      user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)                                         I got the email and password . checkout. 27/Aug/2023 06:27:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 510
[27/Aug/2023 06:27:26] "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1619
[27/Aug/2023 06:28:06] "POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[27/Aug/2023 06:28:06] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1056
                  pqr@gmail.com
                  osama1122334455
[27/Aug/2023 06:28:25] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1078

Comment: What about after authenticate call, is the user null or a valid object?

Comment: @Mohamed ElKalioby
I put the print statement after user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)  and I get in terminal [stu@gmail.com
osama1122334455] . This means user is not None. But the problem is that instead of redirecting to 'home' it is redirecting back to the login page

Comment: Can you update your question with the content of the `home.html`

Comment: @Mohamed ElKalioby. I have updated the question by adding home.html